# how to response from php file to bash script?

Tags: php, bash, curl

I created a website on centos 6. I posted a request to the website (it has a php file) from a bash script with this command:

```
curl -X POST -d text="example" "website"
```

However, I can not return a response from the php file to the bash script. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a HTTP POST request with CURL but you haven't told it to return anything.

Try this:

```
curl -v -X POST -d text="example" "website"
```

This is telling the CURL to verbosely dump everything about the response (header and body).

Here's the documentation for command line usage: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html